# I need to find a way to count the number of repetition of value x where another column value is y

Tags: r

I am using the twitter sentiment analysis for airline flights dataset and It has a column called negative result and another column called airline name. I need to know how to count the repetitions of the value "Bad Flight" in the column negative result Where the airline name is "Virgin America" and repeat this step for "Late Flight" and "Virgin America" and then compare between values and choose the bigger number and use it in plotting.

for example :

Negative Result       Airline Name

Bad Flight            Virgin America

Bad Flight            Virgin America

Bad Flight            Virgin America

Late Flight           Virgin America

Late Flight           Virgin America

Bad Flight            United

Damaged Luggage       United

Bad Flight            United

Late Flight           United

Late Flight           United

Bad Flight            Virgin America

Bad Flight            Virgin America

Late Flight           Virgin America

expected output will be 5 for bad flight and 3 for late flight so after comparing, bad flight will be the value to be plotted.

Comment: Please, see it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

If your dataframe is called `df` you can just do `table(df)`.

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  filter(`Airline Name` == "Virgin America") %>% 
  group_by(`Negative Result`) %>% 
  summarize(n = n())
```